# Deep level recursion with Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am working on a file system `seaweedfs`. and we have saved files on it with proper directory structures as `server`/`camera_id`/`snapshots`/`recordings`/`year`

I am trying to delete the empty folders beneath years.

```elixir
def clean do
  cameras =
    Camera
    |> preload(:owner)
    |> order_by(desc: :created_at)
    |> Evercam.Repo.all()

  years = ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"]
  servers = [@seaweedfs_new, @seaweedfs_old, @seaweedfs_oldest]

  Enum.each(cameras, fn camera ->
    Enum.each(servers, fn server ->
      type = seaweefs_type(server)
      attribute = seaweedfs_attribute(server)
      url = server <> "/#{camera.exid}/snapshots/recordings/"

      Enum.each(years, fn year ->
        final_url = url <> year <> "/"
        request_from_seaweedfs(final_url, type, attribute)
      end)
    end)
  end)
end
```

when the final request goes for a year in `request_from_seaweedfs(final_url, type, attribute)`

it either gives a list like this, `["01", "02", "03"]` or it gives `[]`

in case of `[]` I am just deleting the full tree as

```elixir
url = server/gaol-yard/snapshots/recordings/2016/?recursive=true
hackney = [pool: :seaweedfs_download_pool, recv_timeout: 30_000]
HTTPoison.delete!("#{url}?recursive=true", [], hackney: hackney)
```

But I want to go deeper than that, if the result is not `[]`, then I want to go into months such as

`months = ["01", "02", "03"]`

`final_url = url <> year <> "/" <> "{moth value from the list}"`

for each month, there are consecutive days, and then for days there are hours,

I want to check all this with recursion, such as delete a tree if the last level or any level is empty,

Such as if a camera has, year, months, days and hours but in the last level if the hour gives `[]` delete the whole tree.

This could be achievable with `Enum.each` that each time if I don't get `[]` just again loop through and go till the last level, and where it says `[]` delete that, but can it be possible through more programmatical way? in recursion instead of so many eachs? any help would be helpful thanks

Comment: That nested calls to `Enum.each/2` can be replaced with `for` macro with better readability.

Comment: I would prefer to 
1) write functions for each step separately with case statement about what to do otherwise
2) and then pattern match each function when list is not empty

Comment: @ZubairNabi check answer from Jose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach. Change the current function to call `recursive_delete` with the known `years`:

```
Enum.each(cameras, fn camera ->
  Enum.each(servers, fn server ->
    type = seaweefs_type(server)
    attribute = seaweedfs_attribute(server)
    url = server <> "/#{camera.exid}/snapshots/recordings/"
    recursive_delete(years, url, type, attribute)
  end)
end)
```

And then:

```
def recursive_delete([], _, _, _), do: :done

def recursive_delete(entries, url, type, attribute) do
  Enum.each(entries, fn entry ->
    entry_url = url <> entry <> "/"

    entry_url
    |> request_from_seaweedfs(type, attribute)
    |> recursive_delete(entry_url, type, attribute)
  end)
end
```

Comment: can we also spawn it in some way? for each camera? using `Task.start` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: misunderstood question

So if you want to generate the combinations using recursion, I suppose you could pass your arguments(cameras, servers, years) as a nested list and recursively construct the combinations(consume the first list(cameras), and construct a list by passing the rest of the lists(servers and years) etc.).

This does have the advantage that you can pass an arbitrary number of items or lists and it will construct the combinations instead of adding one more level of `Enum.each` when you want to add another level in the url.

```
defmodule Test do

  def perm(input, acc \\ [])
  def perm([], acc), do: acc
  def perm([first_arr | rest_arr], acc) do
    first_arr
    |> Enum.map(fn val ->
      perm(rest_arr, [val | acc])
    end)
  end

  def flat([fst | rst]) when is_list(fst) do
    case fst do
      [fst1 | _rst1] when is_list(fst1) -> flat(fst ++ rst)
      _ -> [fst] ++ flat(rst)
    end
  end
  def flat(other), do: other
end

cameras = ["gaol-yard", "gaol-yard-1", "gaol-yard-2"]
years =   ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"]
servers = ["seaweedfs_new", "seaweedfs_old", "seaweedfs_oldest"]
# input = [[1,2,3], [:a,:b,:c], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]]

[cameras, years, servers] \
|> Test.perm() \
|> Test.flat \
|> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
```

This should generate something like

```
[
  ["gaol-yard", "2015", "seaweedfs_new"],
  ["gaol-yard", "2015", "seaweedfs_old"],
  ["gaol-yard", "2015", "seaweedfs_oldest"],
  ["gaol-yard", "2016", "seaweedfs_new"],
  ["gaol-yard", "2016", "seaweedfs_old"],
  ["gaol-yard", "2016", "seaweedfs_oldest"],
...
  "gaol-yard-1", "2015", "seaweedfs_old"],
  ["gaol-yard-1", "2015", "seaweedfs_oldest"],
  ["gaol-yard-1", "2016", "seaweedfs_new"],
...
  ["gaol-yard-2", "2019", "seaweedfs_new"],
  ["gaol-yard-2", "2019", "seaweedfs_old"],
  ["gaol-yard-2", "2019", "seaweedfs_oldest"]
]
```

which you can join into one string each

Comment: you didnt get the question actually :)

Comment: Damn.. :), so if the bottom-most directory is empty, delete the whole directory from top?

Comment: Yes its not actual directory as well :) its just HTTP Urls, and its a file system with REST features.

Comment: the delete part which I am showing is deleting the full tree.

Comment: Have updated the answer, hope I got it this time :D

Comment: Naah :D Still didn't get it :P

Comment: The question is: run `request_from_seaweedfs(final_url, type, attribute)` this method until the result is `[]`